# Can’t run zip file: “can't find '__main__' module”

Tags: python, python-3.x

I packed my program in a zip file on my machine, it contains `__main__.pyc` and works well on my machine and other machine, but when I copied it to third machine, it doesn’t work. The only information it gave is

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in 'main.zip'
```

This not really helping for me. I guess it might be because this machine is a virtual machine that runs on the cloud?

python3 on my machine is:

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 24 2013, 20:58:52)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
```

on the 3rd machine is:

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Jan  8 2014, 18:36:12)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
```

The linux version on my machine is

```
Linux Svr2 3.2.0-34-generic-pae #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 11:11:12 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

on the 3rd machine is:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My machine OS is 32bit and the target machine is 64bit, is that what makes the difference?

Comment: yes... definitely. i twigged the 'generic' vs. 'generic-pae', but 32 and 64 bit python are different. note that you should be able to run a 32 bit python on a 64 bit OS, so if you include python itself, you could make it portable that way. or looking into freezing, i don't know what's supported on linux but something like PyInstaller or cx_freeze...

Answer (score 4):

> it contains `__main__.pyc`
>
> My machine OS is 32bit and the target machine is 64bit

Yes, that’s likely what is causing the problems. `pyc` files are *compiled* versions of the source (which is stored in `.py` files). These compiled files are very version specific, and it’s very likely that a `pyc` compiled as 32bit won’t work on a 64bit Python although the version is the same.

Instead of using the `pyc` files, you should just store the `py` files within the zip. That way, the executing Python interpreter can just interpret the code as it needs to.

Comment: I think It should work if `.pyc` is deleted by above user in this third machine. Or wont it?.

Comment: @Drt If the `.py` files are included, then yes.

Comment: i packed py files instead of pyo ,it still doesn't work and give me the same info,and i uploaded py files directly and run it, it gave me 'ImportError: No module named 'zlib'' wasn't it the real reason that bother?

Comment: @user2003548 It’s possible that Python wasn’t compiled with the zlib library on that machine then.

Answer (score 3):

Run it like `python main` instead of `python main.zip`.

Answer (score 0):

got the problem done.

the zip file can't be executed,becuz the python3 on the target machine isn't well installed, and missed a lot of libs like zlib and _ssl.

after reinstall python3,the program can run. doesn't matter the OS bit is different or use pyc.